# how exactly does git submodule work

Tags: git, git-submodules

The `.gitmodule` file only specifies the module repository url. How does `git submodule` know which version to download? It seems to be always checking out the latest version. Then, how does developers ensure compatibility between the main project and the sub modules?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your submodule is represented as a special entry with a special mode (called a **[gitlink](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fast-import.html#_tt_filemodify_tt)**, see "[Nested git repositories without submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980960/git-repository-in-a-git-repository/5981099#5981099)"):
(See "[Checkout past git submodule commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297899/checkout-past-git-submodule-commit/2300638#2300638)")

```
new file mode 160000
index 0000000..4c4c5a2
```

So it isn't checking out the "LATEST" version, but always a specific SHA1, and it does so in a [DETACHED `HEAD` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714) (see "[How to make submodule with detached `HEAD` to be attached to actual `HEAD`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642668/how-to-make-submodule-with-detached-head-to-be-attached-to-actual-head/8644339#8644339)".

That doesn't mean you can't update a submodule, as I explain in "[true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)".

For more on submodules, and on potentially why you might *not* want to use them(!), read the sobering article "[Why your company shouldn’t use Git submodules](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/)", from [Amber Yust](https://plus.google.com/116797686750161798768/posts) (also [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148870/amber)).

Just one small extract, for kicks and giggles (emphasis mine):

> When you invoke `git submodule update` it looks in the parent repository for a SHA for each submodule, goes into those submodules, and checks out the corresponding SHAs.
>   As would be the case if you checked out a SHA in a regular repository, this puts the submodule into a detached HEAD state.
>
> If you then make changes in the submodule and commit then, Git will happily create the commit… and leave you still with a detached HEAD. See where this is going yet?
>
> Say you merge in some more changes which happen to include another submodule update. If you haven’t committed your own submodule change into the parent project yet, Git won’t consider your new commit in the submodule as a conflict, and **if you run `git submodule update` it will happily wipe out your commit without warning, replacing it with that from the branch you just merged in**.
>
> I hope you had your submodule’s `reflog` enabled or still have the old commit in your terminal scrollback, **because otherwise, you just lost all that work you did**.

Err... "ouch".

---

Note that now a submodule can track the latest from a branch: see "[git submodule tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)".