# Git Subtrees vs Monorepo

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, git-subtree, monorepo

We recently decided to move from TFVC to Git and I'm trying to find the best way to design our new Git architecture.

Our code is made of independent but **tightly coupled** modules, let's look at the following projects:

- `CommonLib1`
- `CommonLib2`
- `ApplicationA` (uses `CommonLib1`)
- `ApplicationB` (uses `CommonLib1` & `CommonLib2`)

Although `CommonLib1`/`CommonLib2` are completely independent, almost every new feature for `ApplicationA`/`ApplicationB` would require modifying `CommonLib1`/`CommonLib2`.

Moreover, when adding new features we would like to create a single branch that would span between all our projects.

As far as I understand, I'm left with 2 main options:

1. Create a repo for each project, and add `CommonLib1`/`CommonLib2` as subtrees in `ApplicationA`/`ApplicationB`.
2. Create a single Monorepo for all the projects.

What would be the best Git practice for my situation?

Comment: Google has had success with the giant monorepo. I would suggest starting there and trying to break up the tightly coupled projects.

Comment: I'm sure it will work, but I'm searching for the best practice .. I prefer to start from the beginning in the correct way

Comment: Is "monorepo" a real thing now? I see a number of hits on Google (https://www.google.com/#q=monorepo) but they're all just talking about "dump a bunch of crap into one big repository", which is not really a *thing*. The tag exists now on StackOverflow but has literally nothing for its tag-specific information: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/monorepo/info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git using subtree or submodule to manage external resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668711/git-using-subtree-or-submodule-to-manage-external-resources)

Comment: Also you should *not* do something just because Google does something - they've literally forked the DVCS software they use and rolled their own versions **because publicly available tools are unsuitable for their workflow**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `CommonLib1/CommonLib2` are closely related with `ApplicationA/ApplicationB`, so you’d better use **option2** (**create a single Monorepo for all projects**). The branches structure can be as below:

- `Lib1` branch: manage/develop/update `CommonLib1` in this branch. When it’s updated, you can merge it in `appA` and `appB` branches.
- `Lib2` branch: manage/develop/update `CommonLib2` in this branch. When it’s updated, you can merge it in `appB` branch.
- `appA` branch: manage/develop `ApplicationA` project.
- `appB` branch: manage/develop `ApplicationB` project.