# How to keep two git subdirs in sync in different projects?

Tags: git, synchronization

I have a common directory with `.h` and `.cpp` files in two different projects. Currently I am manually keeping the two in sync. I do not want to take the directory and create a library, because I don't want my users to have a dependency — I just want to have the two subdirs and their files kept in sync. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Why not create a third directory that will be your "server" and then you only make changes to those files. Then the other 2 folders(that your projects use) will then always to a git rebase off that folder... Other than making a scheduled task to do the syncing, I think that will be the easiest

Comment: Use a sub-module? One git repository is the master version and the other uses a version of it as a sub-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tow usual solutions are:

- [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)
- [git subtree merging](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html) (now easier with the [git-subtree.sh script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt))

The idea is to have your common directory as an upstream independent repo, and to update your directory in your different project by:

- updating your submodule
- `git subtree pull  -P <prefix> <repository> <refspec...>`

Considering [how submodules can be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078365/how-exactly-does-git-submodule-work/12078816#12078816), in your case I would recommend the `git-subtree` script.