# How to I push two branches to two separate GitHub remotes?

Tags: git, github

I have a project where the `data` folder need to private (but tracked by VCS). So the entire `git` repo on GitHub is private. The code, however, is quite useful to many people and so I'd like to keep that public.

Currently my repo has only a `master` and `dev`. Once features in `dev` are working, they get merged into `master`. I'd like to create a `no_data` branch and have that push to a public GitHub repo. `master` should continue tracking the private repo. I already have a private GitHub repo for this (let's call it `private_project`). I can create a public repo called `project` for the `no_data` branch.

Questions:
a) How do I set this up so each branch track a separate repo?

b) Since the only thing different between the two branches is that the public one will ignore the `data/` folder, I just plan to add that in a `.gitignore` file. However, I'd like the rest of the code to stay the same in both branches. So I'm afraid that every time I merge `master` to `no_data`, I have to manually resolve the `.gitignore` merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't. This is bound to result in an error on day or another.

Make the `data` directory a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, with its *own* remote upstream repo (the '`private_project`' one), declared with its parent repo (which has the upstream repo '`public_project`').

That way, you can push any branch of the parent repo to 'public_project': it won't matter.
All that the other contributors would get when cloning 'public_project' is the full repo plus a reference to another repo ('`private_project`'), which they can't access (because it is a private repo).
See "[How exactly does git submodule work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078365/how-exactly-does-git-submodule-work/12078816#12078816)".