# How do I add my repos to another persons repo?

Tags: github

I have a microservices application, so the front-end on the first repo and two different backend APIs on two different repos. I want to add all these to someone else's empty repo and I am not sure how to do this.

I tried doing a git remote add of the other persons repo and I get this:

```
danales-MacBook-Pro:freelance-camp-fe danale$ git remote add https://github.com/Meridian-Business-Centers/Interview-Sample-App.git
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from
```

When I do a git remote add microservice master I get this error:

```
danales-MacBook-Pro:freelance-camp-fe danale$ git push microservice master
remote: Permission to Meridian-Business-Centers/Interview-Sample-App.git denied to ldco2016.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Meridian-Business-Centers/Interview-Sample-App.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I tried pushing it to my own forked version and got this error:

```
danales-MacBook-Pro:freelance-camp-fe danale$ git remote add microservice https://github.com/ldco2016/Interview-Sample-App.git
fatal: remote microservice already exists.
danales-MacBook-Pro:freelance-camp-fe danale$ git push microservice master
To https://github.com/ldco2016/Interview-Sample-App.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ldco2016/Interview-Sample-App.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
danales-MacBook-Pro:freelance-camp-fe danale$ git push -u microservice master
To https://github.com/ldco2016/Interview-Sample-App.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ldco2016/Interview-Sample-App.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into every separate repo and add a remote (say, `personal`) with the `url of other persons empty github repo`. Now push the code like `git push personal master`.

Say, you have repo1, repo2 and repo3. And a personal repo `perRepo` (want to add repo1, repo2 and repo3 codes here).

```
# Go into repo1
$ git checkout master    
$ git remote add personal <perRepo-url>
$ git push personal master

# Go into repo2
$ git checkout master    
$ git remote add personal <perRepo-url>
$ git push personal master

# Go into repo3
$ git checkout master    
$ git remote add personal <perRepo-url>
$ git push personal master
```

---

**Add Submodule:** General command: `git submodule add <git@XXX:YYY> <externals>`.

- `git submodule add`: Simply tells Git we are adding a submodule
- `git@XXX:YYY`: External repository URL that is to be added as a submodule
- `externals`: This is the path where the submodule repository will be added to the main repository.

[More Submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Add `repo1`, `repo2` and `repo3` as submodule of `perRepo`.

```
# Go into perRepo
$ git submodule add <repo1-url> <path>
$ git submodule add <repo2-url> <path>
$ git submodule add <repo3-url> <path>

$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

N.B. when `repo1`/`repo2`/`repo3` would be updated you need to run `git submodule update` command to get the updated changes into `perRepo` repo.

Comment: Sajib, so perRepo is the other persons empty github repo, correct? I am trying to add repo1, repo2 and repo3 to that one perRepo. Do I have this correct?

Comment: I tried that Sajib and look at the error I got above.

Comment: You need to give remote name say, personal, git remote add `personal`. General command `git remote add <name> <url> `

Comment: When I do that it says permission denied, I documented the error above.

Comment: Yes, `error: 403` (permission denied). Make sure you have write permission to `Meridian-Business-Centers/Interview-Sample-App` repo.

Comment: I am making little headway here. I tried pushing it as you outlined to a forked repo and got the error above.

Comment: Yes. I think you don't have write permission, then you can create pull request `from your-repo to others-repo`. Or, ask the others-repo author to give write-permission.

Comment: I got this working, but its not what I wanted. It adds everything together. How can the other person distinguish between each separate project? I couldn't tell the difference.

Comment: Here, the projects seems like a single project (It's normal). You can see `commit message/author` by `git log` command to distinguish. Other ways you can use Git Submodule concept keeping the repos as a subdirectory into other's repo. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12078365/4133798

Comment: I think the git submodule is the answer, but I have no idea how to implement. If you want, go ahead and post that as the answer.

Comment: I have added `git submodule` part.

Comment: Sajib, thank you for this, but what about repo3, what happens to that?

Comment: oh, Similar as repo1/repo2 (I missed it). Edited my answer.