# Run travis build for last commit of git submodule

Tags: git, travis-ci, git-submodules

I have git repository with a submodule included. However, whenever I made a commit in the submodule it is not impacted on Travis.

It is always executed on an old version of the submodule.
This is what I get (hiding real data):

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule 'mysubmodule' (https://github.com/xxxxx/myproject.git) registered for path 'somepath'
Cloning into '/home/travis/build/somepath'...
Submodule path 'somepath': checked out '01234567890abcdef':
```

Where `01234567890abcdef` is an old commit, it is not the last one pushed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how exactly does git submodule work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078365/how-exactly-does-git-submodule-work)

Answer (score 2):

Superprojects record the *exact commit* to check out in the submodule.

If you want your superproject to be built based on a newer submodule commit, you must therefore update the superproject.  Adding new commits to the submodule does not affect the superproject; only adding new commits to the superproject can affect the superproject.

Comment: Yes, fixed. Thanks.